# How to get specific version in CVS for co with Jenkins and Hudson?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, cvs

We are trying to configure CVS in our job configuration.

1) In SVN, we could control the SVN co based on svn revision number e.g.

```
> http://server/branch/projectA@revnumber
```

How do we set up in the CVS SCM section where we co the trunk based on HEAD or specific tag to do like what we did for SVN ?

2) what is local directory for in CVS SCM section ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Jenkins (the CVS plugin has diverged quite a lot in Hudson as-far-as-I-know):

1. To set which tag/branch/head to use, change the 'Location' drop-down to Head, Branch or Tag, then enter the tag/branch name in the subsequent input box that appears.
2. The local directory exists to allow you to checkout the module under a different name. This is the same as performing `cvs co -d localName remoteName`. If you don't provide a value in this field then the remote name is used by default.